# Why should I sign my apk before releasing to PlayStore?

Tags: android, security, android-manifest, apk, sign

What exactly is the importance of signing an apk before releasing to the market?

Comment: you cannot release an application with debug sign (it cannot be installed)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From the [Android Documentation for Signing Applications](http://my.fit.edu/~vkepuska/ece5570/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/sdk/docs/tools/publishing/app-signing.html):

> The Android system requires that all installed applications be
>   digitally signed with a certificate whose private key is held by the
>   application's developer. The Android system uses the certificate as a
>   means of identifying the author of an application and establishing
>   trust relationships between applications. The certificate is not used
>   to control which applications the user can install. The certificate
>   does not need to be signed by a certificate authority: it is perfectly
>   allowable, and typical, for Android applications to use self-signed
>   certificates.
>
> The important points to understand about signing Android applications
>   are:
>
> - All applications must be signed. The system will not install an application on an emulator or a device if it is not signed.
> - To test and debug your application, the build tools sign your application with a special debug key that is created by the Android
>     SDK build tools.
> - When you are ready to release your application for end-users, you must sign it with a suitable private key. You cannot publish an
>     application that is signed with the debug key generated by the SDK
>     tools.
> - You can use self-signed certificates to sign your applications. No certificate authority is needed.
> - The system tests a signer certificate's expiration date only at install time. If an application's signer certificate expires after the
>     application is installed, the application will continue to function
>     normally.
> - You can use standard tools — Keytool and Jarsigner — to generate keys and sign your application .apk files.
> - After you sign your application for release, we recommend that you use the zipalign tool to optimize the final APK package.
>
> The Android system will not install or run an application that is not
>   signed appropriately. This applies wherever the Android system is run,
>   whether on an actual device or on the emulator. For this reason, you
>   must set up signing for your application before you can run it or
>   debug it on an emulator or device

**Why means:**

> Some aspects of application signing may affect how you approach the
>   development of your application, **especially if you are planning to
>   release multiple applications**.
>
> In general, the recommended strategy for all developers is to sign all
>   of your applications with the same certificate, throughout the
>   expected lifespan of your applications. There are several reasons why
>   you should do so:
>
> - **Application upgrade** – As you release updates to your application, you must continue to sign the updates with the same
>     certificate or set of certificates, if you want users to be able to
>     upgrade seamlessly to the new version. When the system is installing
>     an update to an application, it compares the certificate(s) in the new
>     version with those in the existing version. If the certificates match
>     exactly, including both the certificate data and order, then the
>     system allows the update. If you sign the new version without using
>     matching certificates, you must also assign a different package name
>     to the application — in this case, the user installs the new version
>     as a completely new application.
> - **Application modularity** – The Android system allows applications that are signed by the same certificate to run in the same process, if
>     the applications so requests, so that the system treats them as a
>     single application. In this way you can deploy your  application in
>     modules, and users can update each of the modules independently if
>     needed.
> - **Code/data sharing through permissions** – The Android system provides signature-based permissions enforcement, so that an
>     application can expose functionality to another application that is
>     signed with a specified certificate. By signing multiple applications
>     with the same certificate and using signature-based permissions
>     checks, your applications can share code and data in a secure manner.
>
> Another important consideration in determining your signing strategy
>   is how to set the validity period of the key that you will use to sign
>   your applications.
>
> - If you plan to support upgrades for a single application, you should ensure that your key has a validity period that exceeds the expected
>     lifespan of that application. A validity period of 25 years or more is
>     recommended. When your key's validity period expires, users will no
>     longer be able to seamlessly upgrade to new versions of your
>     application.
> - If you will sign multiple distinct applications with the same key, you should ensure that your key's validity period exceeds the expected
>     lifespan of all versions of all of the applications, including
>     dependent applications that may be added to the suite in the future.
> - If you plan to publish your application(s) on Google Play, the key you use to sign the application(s) must have a validity period ending
>     after 22 October 2033. Google Play enforces this requirement to ensure
>     that users can seamlessly upgrade applications when new versions are
>     available.

Comment: My question was why android OS restricts installation without signed APK, I mean what purpose it serves. @shylendra

Comment: @Hissain To upgrade your application with your own certificate and to release multiple applications in play store we need to sign it so that they will accept your application . See my edited answer

Comment: When you copy text from other sources, you *must* indicate that you've copied it by placing the copied text in block quotes. Please see [How to reference material written by others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: What is meant by 'Establishing trust relationships between applications'?
And how is the 'author' known based on signing?

Comment: quoting from just android pages was not something that was being sought in the question I guess. What was being asked was how exactly does app signing help thus making it important for apps to be signed before being released.

Comment: @qre0ct Haha have you read why means part in the above answer., If you could read this carefully you'll let you know why it is..

`The Android system will not install or run an application that is not signed appropriately. This applies wherever the Android system is run, whether on an actual device or on the emulator. For this reason, you must set up signing for your application before you can run it or debug it on an emulator or device`

Comment: @ShylendraMadda with all due respect, 2 things :
1. Your quote above still does not clarify the WHY part of the question. It's like the doc says something should be done a certain way so just do it, else it will break, but without actually giving any insight/rationale into WHY does the doc say it would break, which IMHO would give a better understanding than just blindly following something.

Comment: @ShylendraMadda 2. **Why down vote an accepted answer** - the person who posted the question might have gotten satisfied with your answer. But, again IMHO, SO is used by the whole community, of which am an integral part, & I would like the questions posted here have the most clear & unambiguous answers possible so that the answer helps clear concepts rather than just help with the job at hand.

Comment: @qre0ct So if you want more clarity then go and research on it Why.., When you satisfy then post it as a new answer here.. It may helps some one..

Comment: @ShylendraMadda You might just have given a reference link to the answer.

Comment: @AnkitShubham Yes it is giving answer to the question asked by OP. That is why he accepted it. ;P

Answer (score 11):

**Why?**

Developers can prevent someone from tampering with their app.

**Sign to protect your app!**

This works in the public key cryptography. You are the only one who has the private key. You are the only one who can sign your apps. The user can trust the app being directly from you. It is mathematically proven to be unfeasible to tamper with the app if the private key is not available.

You know, in public key cryptography there are two keys like the sides of a coin. The private and the public key. You keep the private key secret. You lock it away and keep it secure. On the other hand you publish your public key.

These keys are like the sides of a coin because what you encrypt with one key you decrypt with the other key.

And how is this applied for app signing?

Signing is encrypting with the private key.

Because you publish the public key the app store and the users have your public key. They can decrypt your app and therefore know for sure that the app is really your own. Android and the app store does this for them.

**The app store verifies the signature by decrypting with the public key.**

That's all, folks.

Answer (score -3):

**Sign Apk:**
Generating a signed apk means to encrypt your apk with a password or a key that is known only to you and you have to remember this apk forever as if for any further upgradation done on your app you have to access it with your app then.