# How to get the updated Apk file from the android studio.?

Tags: android, apk

I am developing an android application. All the things is going well when I run the application into genymotion virtual device.And Since the apk is stored in F:...\app\build\outputs\apk  location. So I just want to collect it from this location and download it to install in a android phone.As I simultaneously updating the application with code but this apk doesn't provide me the updated apk file according to the updated code .They just give me the old apk file even if i run my application again and again from the android studio. Can anyone suggest me why this is happening ??? I just want to run this apk into phone or download this apk file for another purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to *Build > Build APK* to generate a normal APK.
Go to *Build > Generate Signed APK* to generate signed APK.

Signed APK are those which we generate to release our application. Here it is, why is it necessary to generate signed APKs: [Why should I Sign my Application APK before release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906799/why-should-i-sign-my-application-apk-before-release)

If you build a debug APK, it will still work on all devices but you cannot release it.

Answer (score 1):

> This three steps will do Go build->Build apk

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: thn put tick in left side of my ans!! :-) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Original answer

Signed apk is needed to install in any other non debug device. This will be same as the debug app that runs in your test device/emulator.

Build -> Generate signed apk

Comment: Generate signed apk was what I answered earlier. Anyway, never mind if your problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

From terminal run the following command to make sure that you get the updated apk.

```
    1. gradle clean (from windows ) 
         -or-
       ./gradlew clean (from linux) -
```

> Above command deletes the build folder.

```
2. gradle build (from windows)
   -or-
   ./gradlew build(from linux)
```

> Above command builds all the flavor for your application.