# Certificate info when signing apps in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to sign my app and I'm generating a key to sign.

There is some info that I should enter in order to generate a key.(certificate field)

What this info is about and why do we need this?

Can I reset my password or even REGENERATE new key if I remember this info?
So I can sign the the app with new generated key and send it to existing listing in Google Play

[image: certificate]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yes, but the only info I've found there is Certificate: Enter some information about yourself for your certificate. This information is not displayed in your app, but is included in your certificate as part of the APK.

Comment: Your question has been answered here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906799/why-should-i-sign-my-application-apk-before-release

Comment: @GeraldTDPI no it is not. What I'm asking, why do we need certificate credentials entered and are they important.

Answer (score 0):

"All applications must be signed. The system will not install an application on an emulator or a device if it is not signed"

And i think that's why its important :))

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I'm asking of

Comment: Got it pal, Its okay :))